# Which drawing method should I use for a finite state machine in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I have a finite state machine with 4 states and a few dozen arrows.

Which method should I use to draw it?

[Graph Drawing section](https://mirror.szerverem.hu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=415) of the pgf manual

uses \graph

[The Petri net example](https://mirror.szerverem.hu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=50)

uses \node and \edge

The above Graph Drawing section lists a few more.

Which one fits best the finite state machine drawing task?

EDIT: [The Automata Drawing Library](https://mirror.szerverem.hu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=571) gives another method but I am not sure whether my few dozen arrows are correctly handled by it

Comment: For automaton is dedicated `automata` TikZ library.

Comment: The `automata` and the `petri` library only offer some styles and shortcuts to change the visual output of nodes/edges. They don't help at all with placing nodes and connecting them. The `graphs` library and its `graph` syntax does help with placing nodes and connecting them (but the same is doable with `\node`s and `edge`s). The `graphdrawing` library has a Lua backend that helps with placing nodes in very specific automatic ways. All four can be used together or each on its own.